# Quickest Way to Copy SQL Data

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access, console-application

I could use some suggestions / ideas.
I wrote a console application that queries all data from a table in MS Access (I know, but I inherited it) to a SQL table. It runs every morning as a scheduled task. The fields between the two tables are not identical. Currently I select all data from the MS Access table, loop through the dataset and insert each row into the SQL table. I also write a quick log file in the process. It works, but it's not fast. I would appreciate any ideas that you may have to improve the process.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SqlBulkCopy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

It's **way** faster than individual `insert` statements.

You have to increment your own identity field value for the primary key.  To do that, first grab the last identity field value where you left off:

`select top 1 id_customer
from customers
order by id_customer desc`

Then increment an `int` variable as you loop through your `DataSet`.

Or you can use [GUID for primary key column](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html) instead.

Example code for using SqlBulkCopy:

```
public static void BulkLoadDataTable(DataTable table, string destinationTable)
{
  using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(_connectionString))
  {
    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 1200;
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTable;
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
  }
}
```

Strongly Typed DataTable:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

public class CustomersDataTable : DataTable
{
  public CustomersDataTable() : base()
  {
    base.TableName = "Customers";
    Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id_customer", typeof(int)));
    Columns.Add(new DataColumn("first_name", typeof(string)));
    Columns.Add(new DataColumn("last_name", typeof(string)));
    Columns.Add(new DataColumn("active", typeof(bool)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Creating your own primary key is only necessary in extreme cases when your inserts are in the millions of records.  But I agree with John that SqlBulkCopy is the way to go.

Comment: Looks like the BulkCopyClass is the way to go. But, what happens when the field attributes do not match? For example, a string field in access and a Boolean field in SQL.

Comment: Well you can loop through your data and build a `DataTable` exactly the way you want it in SQL Server, i.e. 'bit' column for a 'bool'.  SQL Server should be able to convert data points in an untyped `DataTable` to the proper type in your schema, but personally, I would create a **strongly typed DataTable** (see above).  You could also write out a .CSV and bulk copy that. Doing all this work in a loop in your code will take relatively little time.  The main point is 1000's of individual `insert` statements will waste **TONS** of time!

Comment: Thanks JohnB - your suggestion worked like a charm. After creating the strongly typed DataTable it took less than a second to perform the work (before it was like 30 seconds).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at SSIS packages? I would look into that first. If you don't have access to that, then look into the SqlBulkCopy class mentioned here already.

You could also look into using [SELECT statement with an INSERT](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-select-to-insert-records).

Comment: SELECT statement with an INSERT would be slow though.

Comment: Yeah but it's still faster than individual inserts. It would be my last choice but I figured I'd present the option. SSIS would be the way to go in my opinion.

Comment: Why would a batch insert using INSERT with a SELECT statement be slow?